# how Use 'AND' 'OR' operation using Parse API in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I  am using `parse.com` for storing data. I want to retrieve the objects with `and` & `OR` conditions using Parse API in `objective -c`

My Code is :

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"UserInfo"];
    [query whereKey:@"location" nearGeoPoint:_geoPoint withinMiles:5];
    [query whereKey:@"Sex" equalTo:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:SELECTED_LOOKINGFOR]]];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can give multiple constraints and objects will only be in the results if they match all of the constraints. In other words, it's like an AND of constraints. For Example to get all players named NOT Michael Yabuti AND aged greater than 18:

```
[query whereKey:@"playerName" notEqualTo:@"Michael Yabuti"];
[query whereKey:@"playerAge" greaterThan:@18];

// Using NSPredicate
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:   @"playerName != 'Michael Yabuti' AND playerAge > 18"];
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"GameScore" predicate:predicate];
```

For OR Query, You can use [Compound Queries](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#queries-compound/iOS) of Parse.e.g. to get all results where wins are greater than 150 or less than 5 you do something like this Like this:

```
PFQuery *lotsOfWins = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Player"];
[lotsOfWins whereKey:@"wins" greaterThan:[NSNumber numberWithInt:150]];

PFQuery *fewWins = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Player"];
[fewWins whereKey:@"wins" lessThan:[NSNumber numberWithInt:5]];

PFQuery *query = [PFQuery orQueryWithSubqueries:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:fewWins,lotsOfWins,nil]];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
  // results contains players with lots of wins or only a few wins.
}];
```

Now as I hope you have understood the concept and mechanism, you may modify your query as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using NSPredicate with PFQuery.

See below example

```
NSPredicate *predicateTeamId = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"teamid = %@", objSchedule[@"teamid"]];

NSPredicate *predicateOppTeamId = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"teamid = %@", objSchedule[@"opponentteamid"]];

NSPredicate *predicateBothTeam = [NSCompoundPredicate orPredicateWithSubpredicates:@[predicateTeamId,predicateOppTeamId]];

PFQuery * qryTeam = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:Parse_Class_Teams predicate:predicateBothTeam];
```

For more details , you can visit this link https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/guide#queries-specifying-constraints-with-nspredicate link.